# why $(3/4,3/4)\notin B(0,1)$?

Tags: general-topology

I have an excerpt from my textbook which explain that elements of the product topology are not all of the from $U_1\times U_2$ for $U_i\in\mathcal{T}_i$ , where the profuct topology is defined as :

> Suppose that $(T_1,\mathcal{T}_1)$ and $(T_2,\mathcal{T}_2)$ are two topological spaces. Then the product topology on $T_1\times T_2$ is the topology with basis $$\mathcal{B}=\{U_1\times U_2:  U_1\in\mathcal{t}_1,U_2\in\mathcal{T}_2\}$$
>   We call $(T_1,\times T_2, \mathcal{T})$ the topological product on $T_1$ and $T_2$

So my textbook gives this example:

> Consider $B(0,1)\in\Bbb R^2$, which is open in the product topology (it is open for the usual metric $\Bbb R^2$, whicih is the 'product metric', $\mathcal{q}_p$ with $p=2$). Suppose $B(0,1)=U_1\times U_2$. Then $(3/4,0)\in B(0,1)$,so $3/4\in U_1$,and $(0,3/4)\in B(0,1)$,so $3/4\in U_2$: but then $U_1\times U_2 \ni (3/4,3/4)\notin B(0,1)$

So I don't exactly understand why $(3/4,3/4)\notin B(0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x,y) \in B(0,1)  \iff x^2+y^2 < 1.$

But this is not true for $x=y=3/4.$

Answer (score 0):

The precise point where your thinking went wrong is where you assumed $B(0,1) = U_1 \times U_2$.  In other words, you assumed $B(0,1)$ *is a basis element* in the product topology.  This is incorrect; these basis elements are, geometrically, *rectangles*, while $B(0,1)$, a circle, can only be expressed as a union of *infinitely many* of these rectangles.  You will find that while (3/4,0) fits in some of the rectangles which make up the circle, and (0,3/4) fits in others, there is no one rectangle *that fits in the circle* and contains both, hence your conclusion that one must also contains (3/4,3/4) fails.